# Invalid header value b'328fff54abb8128f17ea704be7f24fe7\n'

Tags: python

```py
@app.route('/voiceTest_and_download/<int:story_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voiceTest_and_download(story_id):
    """Check voice and download mp3 file."""
    global is_speaking  # Access the global variable
    is_speaking = False
    choice_voice = request.form.get('choice_voice')
    choice_model = request.form.get('choice_model')
    session = db.session
    story = session.get(Story, story_id)
    if story:
        
        if 'listen_voice' in request.form:
            audio = elevenlabs.generate(text="something text for testing",
                                        voice=choice_voice,
                                        model="eleven_multilingual_v2")
            elevenlabs.play(audio)
            return render_template('voiceTest_and_download.html', story=story)
```

Show it
"ValueError: Invalid header value b'328fff54abb8128f17ea704be7f24fe7\n'"

show this line is problem.

```
audio = elevenlabs.generate(text="something",
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I cannot use a 'post' request.I try to use only elevenlabs libary.

Answer (score 1):

Your API key value is not properly formatted. Remove the new line character at the end of your API key (`\n`).

Make sure its something like this.

```py
from elevenlabs import set_api_key
set_api_key("<API_KEY>")
print("No new lines!")
```

Or if you are using environment variable, check the value of `ELEVEN_API_KEY` and make sure there is no new line at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much. Here create a new line in the API key. I remove the extra line in my API key, and then it works.